# Accepting user input for a variable

Tags: variables, input, forth

So, this should be an easy question for anyone who has used FORTH before, but I am a newbie trying to learn how to code this language (and this is a lot different than C++).

Anyways, I'm just trying to create a variable in FORTH called "Height" and I want a user to be able to input a value for "Height" whenever a certain word "setHeight" is called. However, everything I try seems to be failing because I don't know how to set up the variable nor how to grab user input and put it in the variable.

```
    VARIABLE Height 5 ALLOT
    : setHeight 5 ACCEPT ATOI CR ;
```

I hope this is an easy problem to fix, and any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Rosettacode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code) input/output examples for [string or number input in FORTH](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/User_input/Text#Forth):

**String Input**

```
: INPUT$ ( n -- addr n )
   PAD SWAP ACCEPT
   PAD SWAP ;
```

**Number Input**

```
: INPUT# ( -- u true | false )
  0. 16 INPUT$ DUP >R
  >NUMBER NIP NIP 
  R> <> DUP 0= IF NIP THEN ;
```

Answer (score 0):

A big point to remember for your self-edification -- C++ is heavily typecasted, Forth is the complete opposite. Do you want Height to be a string, an integer, or a float, and is it signed or unsigned? Each has its own use cases. Whatever you choose, you must interact with the Height variable with the type you choose kept in mind. Think about what your bits mean every time.

Judging by your ATOI call, I assume you want the value of Height as an integer. A 5 byte integer is unusual, though, so I'm still not certain. But here goes with that assumption:

```
VARIABLE Height 1 CELLS ALLOT
VARIABLE StrBuffer 7 ALLOT

: setHeight ( -- )
  StrBuffer 8 ACCEPT
  DECIMAL ATOI Height ! ;
```

The CELLS call makes sure you're creating a variable with the number of bits your CPU prefers. The DECIMAL call makes sure you didn't change to HEX somewhere along the way before your ATOI.

Creating the StrBuffer variable is one of numerous ways to get a scratch space for strings. Assuming your CELL is 16-bit, you will need a maximum of 7 characters for a zero-terminated 16-bit signed integer -- for example, "-32767\0". Some implementations have PAD, which could be used instead of creating your own buffer. Another common word is SCRATCH, but I don't think it works the way we want.

If you stick with creating your own string buffer space, which I personally like because you know exactly how much space you got, then consider creating one large buffer for all your words' string handling needs. For example:

```
VARIABLE StrBuffer 201 ALLOT
```

This also keeps you from having to make the 16-bit CELL assumption, as 200 characters easily accommodates a 64-bit signed integer, in case that's your implementation's CELL size now or some day down the road.

Comment: As PAD is a standard word in the CORE wordset, all standard Forths are _required_ to have PAD. Since PAD is intended to be used as just this sort of temporary buffer, I don't see the point in creating your own buffer for this.

Comment: @MichaelMorris In embedded applications designed to run as a compiled app, PAD may exist but it may not work. For example, the compiled dictionary is hard written to Flash memory when a device is delivered, and is never interactive for the user. PAD is often implemented by using the top of the dictionary, but if there's no support to write to Flash, writing to PAD would fail. Also, FWIW, it's part of the CORE EXT wordset, not CORE.